# Why is my variable not defined and how do i fix this?

Tags: python, list, text-files

```
with open("RoundOneTotalScores.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    values = [int(line.split(',')[1]) for line in lines]
    smallest = (min(values))
    smallest2 = (sorted(values)[:2])
    highest4 = (sorted(values)[2:])

W1 = str(highest4[0])
W2 = str(highest4[1])
W3 = str(highest4[2])
W4 = str(highest4[3])

Myfile = open("RoundOneTotalScores.txt", "r")

for line in Myfile:
    if W1 in line.split(",")[1]:
        W1L = (line.split(",")[0])

for line in Myfile:
    if W2 in line.split(",")[1]:
        W2L = (line.split(",")[0])

for line in Myfile:
    if W3 in line.split(",")[1]:
        W3L = (line.split(",")[0])

for line in Myfile:
    if W4 in line.split(",")[1]:
        W4L = (line.split(",")[0])

Myfile = open("RoundOneWinners.txt", "a")

Myfile.write(W1L)
Myfile.write(",")
Myfile.write(W1)
Myfile.write("\n")
Myfile.write(W2L)
Myfile.write(",")
Myfile.write(W2)
Myfile.write("\n")
Myfile.write(W3L)
Myfile.write(",")
Myfile.write(W3)
Myfile.write("\n")
Myfile.write(W4L)
Myfile.write(",")
Myfile.write(W4)

Myfile.close()
```

The code above does the following: opens a text file which contains six letters, each with a number. It finds the four highest of those numbers and then finds the equivalent letters. When I try to save it to a new text file, this error comes up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\NEA Real\Test5.py", line 37, in <module>
Myfile.write(W2L)
NameError: name 'W2L' is not defined
```

Why is W2L not defined and how do I define it?

Comment: Does the second object (split by a comma) exist in your text document at the beginning - `RoundOneTotalScores.txt`?

Comment: Yes, the text file is set out as A, 23 \n B, 14 \n etc. for six letters and they are all on new lines

Comment: `int(line.split(',')[1]` It may be the `[1]` that is the issue. You are collecting only the second item in the list, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: What would you suggest I put instead then?

Answer (score 5):

Because there will only defined, if this condition is `true`:

```
if W2 in line.split(",")[1]:
```

### EDIT

Added solutions from the commend of [roganjosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254013/why-is-my-variable-not-defined-and-how-do-i-fix-this/46254061#comment79471706_46254061) and [me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254013/why-is-my-variable-not-defined-and-how-do-i-fix-this/46254061#comment79471729_46254061).

Define all `W1L - W4L` on the top with an empty string.

```
W1L = ''
W2L = ''
W3L = ''
W4L = ''
```

or in else:

```
for line in Myfile:
    if W2 in line.split(",")[1]:
        W2L = (line.split(",")[0])
    else:
        W2L = ''
```

Comment: When I did that, this error came up: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

Comment: @Megan an empty string might be more appropriate e.g. `W1L = ''`

Comment: Yes. Because you cant write a None in your File. I Don't no what you want to do if the condition is no true. Maybe do an `else:` and write a empty string in the Variable, then there will be write nothing in the File.

Answer (score 2):

You can't iterate over the file multiple times like this; after the first loop completes, you have reached the end of the file, and the next three loops never do anything; there is no more data to read.

Instead, combine your loops into *one*:

```
for line in Myfile:
    value, field = line.split(",")[0:2]
    if W1 in field:
        W1L = value

    if W2 in field:
        W2L = value

    if W3 in field:
        W3L = value

    if W4 in field:
        W4L = value
```

There is still the risk that any particular variable does not get set, if the corresponding tag is not found. There is also a chance that you find the same tag multiple times, in which case you will only record the last one found.

Answer (score 2):

When you read the entire file, the read cursor reaches the end of the file. You need to set it to the beginning using `seek(0)` if you want to read it again.

```
Myfile = open("RoundOneTotalScores.txt", "r")

for line in Myfile:
    if W1 in line.split(",")[1]:
        W1L = (line.split(",")[0])

Myfile.seek(0)

for line in Myfile:
    if W2 in line.split(",")[1]:
        W2L = (line.split(",")[0])
```

Comment: This fixes the immediate problem, but leaves the issue of unnecessarily re-reading the file multiple times.

Comment: @chepner Agreed!! I just want to let Megan know why she is getting the error that W2L is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Try using dictionaries, avoiding variables, so if any line in file is missing - NameError wont be raised. Here is some example, how could you write your code:

```
scores = {}

with open("RoundOneTotalScores.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        user, score = line.split(',')
        user = user.strip()
        scores[user.strip()] = int(score)

winners_scores = sorted(scores.values())[2:]

winners = {k: v for k, v in scores.items() if v in winners_scores}

with open("RoundOneWinners.txt", "a") as f:
    for winner_and_score in winners.items():
        f.write(','.join(winner_and_score))
```